What cause to "Application failed to start signal : killed" when deploying shiny app
I'm familiar with shiny app, and deployment but I recently got this issue:
"The application failed to start signal : killed"
This happened after adding data to my shiny app. So I removed this data since it seems that shinyapps.io (free account) have memory limits. But it didn't change anything.
I also tried to remove more data, no changement.
I thank that the duration of the shiny app on shinyapps.io was reached so I tried to deploy the app on another account. Didn't works, same error.
Lastly, I tried to update R and got uncompatibility message so I got back to an old R version.
Here's the Deploy:
── Deploying to server ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Waiting for task: 1481502733
  building: Processing bundle: 9403606
  building: Building image: 11545462
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 11545462
  deploying: Starting instances
  rollforward: Activating new instances
  success: Stopping old instances
── Deployment complete 

Any ideas, because I'm sincerely lost. Thank you.
